# Cakephp getting session variable in model without using Auth component

Tags: cakephp

I want to get my session variables in my model. Im not using Auth component. Is there any alternate way ?

Thanks
Binoy

Comment: Sessions and the AuthComponent have little to do with each other. Trying to access session variables from the model sounds like bad MVC separation. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Ok.. I will explain.. I need to make a backup (like a log) of current record before updating with new data. So Im writing the code in beforeSave in model and I need to get who is updating the record that will be there in session.

Comment: Check out alkemann's revision and logable behaviors. http://github.com/alkemann/CakePHP-Asset

Comment: @neilcrookes I was going to post the same link. Even if @binoy can't use it directly, it's a good reference of how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use the Session helper to do,

```
$this->Session->write('key','value');
```

But as the comment states, you'll be wanting to set a variable in your model and then use the session to write the same value into that variable in the model, rather than accessing the session actually in the model.

```
Class MyModel Extends AppModel{
  var $username;
  var $password;
}
```

Then in your controller you could use something along the lines of,

```
$this->MyModel->username = $this->Session->read('User.id');
$this->MyModel->password = $this->Session->read('User.password');
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller File : use Session helper

```
class AppController extends Controller {
     var $helpers = array('Session');
     function index()
     {
        $this->Session->write('answer', '10'); //$this->Session->write('key','value');
     }
     ....
 }
```

Now you can access this varibale in your model :

```
 class AppModel extends Model {

    function validateanswer(){
        CakeSession::read('answer');/*Here u can get value of varibale answer which you set through controller*/
    }
 }
```